# Windows deletes make executable file upon running. Why?

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to get some code running which uses `make`. I've downloaded and installed both MinGW (standard 32 bit) and TDM-GCCs flavor of MinGW on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

When I run `make` (i.e. `mingw32-make.exe`) **in Administrator mode**, I get the following error message:

> Windows cannot access the specified path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

The weird/scary part is that, upon running, it **immediately deletes the exe file**.

I ran a checksum SHA1 as recommended in the comments using the Microsoft (R) File Checksum Integrity Verifier V2.05:

```
C:\path\to\folder>fciv.exe -sha1 mingw32-make.exe
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
c8ae5c780ab7bed652883d6443b5bfe5e23d30c9 mingw32-make.exe
```

I don't understand what this output means, but maybe it's helpful to someone.

Notes:

1. This happens regardless of where the file is located on my pc.
2. This behavior is specific to the `make` program (others such as `gfortran` and `gcc` appear to be working fine)
3. Renaming the file makes no difference.
4. I am an administrator on the pc
5. Same behavior when I run the program from the explorer or command line.
6. My anti-virus program (Avast) does not detect any problems with the file when I scan it.
7. I got the MinGW setup file from [this SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download) page.
8. I got the TDM-GCC web installer from [this page](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download).
9. The file size is 219,662 bytes (from both the main MinGW and TDM-GCC packages)
10. I have run `make` from the command line where I have started the command prompt by way of selecting `Run as Administrator` in the context menu.
11. I have also tried to run `make` by selecting `Run as Administrator` when I have it selected.
12. I run the command `mingw32-make` when this behavior occurs. I have also tried renaming it to things like `make` and `foo` with the same result.
13. The first time this happened with both MinGW it deleted the original file and I re-installed it using the `mingw-get` application. From thereon after I started making copies of the original `mingw32-make` for testing.
14. For the `make` executable, I have all permissions (including Read & execute) except the special permissions field.

Comment: Anti-virus software?

Comment: @tripleee I don't think so. Avast has been pretty vocal in the past when it doesn't like something I'm running.

Comment: In order for anyone to repro this, let alone troubleshoot, you need to provide very specific details about this exact binary. Exactly where did you obtain it; what is its size and SHA1 checksum?

Comment: @tripleee edited my question to include the requested info.

Comment: Thanks. The SHA1 signature is a simple way for someone to verify that they have exactly the same file. Even a one-bit difference in the binary will produce a completely different hash.

Comment: What is the exact console command you run by which `mingw32-make.exe` is deleted? And if it is deleted, how do you keep experimentally running it? Are you keeping a backup? Are your re-installing the toolchain?

Comment: @MikeKinghan See notes 12 and 13.

Comment: Does the program actually have read+execute permission for you? Context-menu -> Properties -> Security.
Are any Denials ticked in Permissions for Administrators or Permissions for Authenticated Users?

Comment: @MikeKinghan See note 14. No denials.

Comment: My TDM-GCC make has the same size and checksum as yours. It's pukka.
I don't use Avast. I know you've scanned it but what happens if you
disconnect from the Internet and turn Avast right off?

Comment: Try using Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to see which process is deleting the executable.

Comment: @MikeKinghan You were right: it was Avast. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good suggestion. That was the key to figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the process manager I found out it was indeed Avast that was the problem :S A couple of lines revealed avast actually deleted the file before windows got around to executing it, which was the reason for the windows message. I put Avast on 'Silent Mode' a while back; I thought the only purpose of this mode was to suppress notifications about minor updates, but apparently it also gave Avast permission to deal with 'threats' silently as well.

After figuring that out the solution was straightforward. I just went into the settings and created an exception for the `mingw32-make.exe` file. It now runs without issue.

Thanks very much for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

User account has administrator privilege but when user started to work , not all privilege are taken in account , just start your application for compiling with run with administrator mode try this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc781763(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I am the only user on this computer; I can't run as any other user.

Comment: actually when you have any app and  you want it run with administrator privileged , then you have explicitly specify that you want it run with admin privilege .

Comment: This doesn't explain why the file would disappear.